# Prevent control from resizing with form

Tags: vb.net

What am i doing wrong.

I have datagrid on form. Form is resizable but i need to stick the original dimensions of datagrid without resizing it with form.

```
Anchor of grid is set to : top, left
```

And

```
Form : Resizable
```

[image]

Comment: If the anchor is set to top, left, it should stay the same size. In fact, if the size is to change, then at least one of these pairs should be set as the anchor : `top, bottom`; `left, right`.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ i think there is something else. Anchor is set as you said

Comment: What about docking. Do you have it docked?  That will cause this behavior

Comment: @CharlesMay that was not causing this problem. Just edited

Answer (score 0):

You also have a "Locked" property to set True, but this should not be required.
You did right, so I'm wondering if you have something in code which is able to change the DataGridView behavior.